# Can’t connect to insecure Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I’m on a working vacation in a remote cabin with no cell service, but there is Wi-Fi.  Every device my family has with them can connect to the cabins Wi-Fi, except my work Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, which is the only Linux laptop I have with me and the one I need for work. I’m currently typing this from my daughters iPad.

I’ve attempted the normal troubleshooting, including reboooting, turning Wi-Fi on and off and looking at nmcli.

Nmcli shows the only SSID, 3-4 bars of signal and no security. However, when I try to connect with nmcli dev wifi con “Grey Whale” I get Error 53, wifi network could not be found.

Looking at the wpa_supplicant journal, I just see auth_failures with reason CONN_FAILED

How can I connect to this Wi-Fi?

UPDATE:

Here’s the output of the NetworkManager command as suggested by waltinator.

[image: NetworkManager Log]

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.